# C# Azure Event Grid publish EventGridTopicEvent

Tags: c#, azure, event-handling

I have scenario where I need to publish `EventGridTopicEvent` data and at the same time I need to store this event information in the Azure Storage Table. I would like to know is there any way to get the information(like T/F) if Publish event successfully done or not(any error), If it is published successfully then only I should save the data into Table storage.

I need to handle the above logic via C# Event Handler(Mediator), I tried with C# `TransactionScope` but it is not having mechanism like Rollback. If event is not published then rollback the event as well as not store anything in the table storage or I should not make a call to handle the database transaction.

I have also tried `_mediator.Publish(request).IsCompletedSuccessfully` but it is giving true always even though I pass invalid request data.

code snippet

```
public async Task<Result<Response<XYZ>>> Handle(EventGridTopicEvent request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
    {
        try
        {
            bool eventPublishStatus = _mediator.Publish(request).IsCompletedSuccessfully;
            if (eventPublishStatus)
            {
                //Insert request data to Table storage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the handler of the request in which the data is published to the event grid.

Comment: Your question does not contain an actual error you encounter and lacks the details that can be used to give a conclusive answer. I did attempt to provide one, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have scenario where I need to publish "EventGridTopicEvent" data and at the same time I need to store this event information in the Azure Storage Table. I would like to know is there any way to get the information(like T/F) if Publish event successfully done or not(any error), If it is published successfully then only I should save the data into Table storage.

What do you mean with the publish event being succesfully done or not?

- If you mean it is published to the Event Grid, then it is easy: when the call to the Event Grid SDK is completed without an exception the data is published to the Event Grid succesfully.
- If you want to know whether all the consumers of the event did get the data and processed it succesfully then you have a challenge there.

Within the context of your application it is hard to tell if all the consumers got the event and processed it as the Event Grid is an asynchronous eventing platform. If it fails to deliver the event it will retry it for some time and after that the event can be transferred to a dead letter store ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery)). In reality this means that there can be a delay between the data being published and the data being consumed. Given that, you can easily see how difficult it would be for your application to know all data is received and processed succesfully.

If you want to store the data as some kind of log of what data is succesfully published to the event grid you might actually create a subscription to the event grid and use that to store the published data in the table storage.